# File Upload component in Flow - no indication that files where uploaded

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload, flow-builder

I am using the File Upload component in Flow.

It works good, but I have no indication that the files where uploaded.

So the flow looks exactly the same before and after I upload files:

**Before clicking `Upload Files`:**

[image]

**After clicking `Upload Files`:**

The window for selecting files from the hard drive is opened:
[image]

**After selecting files to upload:**

[image]

**After clicking `Done`:**

[image]

**QUESTION**

Can I have an event or an indication or a visual change when file is finishing uploading?

This is a very bad user experience, the user does not know if files where uploaded and how many etc - is this the way Salesforce developed this component? it looks very bad...

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution for this until such time as SFDC enhances the OOTB component can be found in the [UnofficialSF](https://unofficialsf.com/) set of Flow components.

Specifically, the [File Uploader Improved component](https://unofficialsf.com/from-josh-dayment-improved-file-upload-in-flow-screens/) *(a packaged LWC)*

Here's what it looks like:

### **Before upload**

[image]

### **After upload**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `Store Output Values` you have `Content Document IDs` and `Uploaded File Names`. You can use text collection variables for storing these. You can show these details after clicking on done.

[image]

**--- added ---**

If the collection variable is shown in same screen, its not updating. Instead you need to put the collection variable in next screen in `Output text`.

[image]

On next screen:

[image]

Will let you know if I come across a solution where we can show in same screen.

Note: Using custom component, you can use `lightning:fileUpload` component and `onuploadfinished` event which fires when you click on `Done` and you can show immediately with all details like Name, Size, type etc

**-------------------------------------------------------------**
**---- added --------------------------------------------------**
**-------------------------------------------------------------**

If you would like to create custom component, there is a generic component (in-progress) which you can use, you get some inferences. This is git repo: https://github.com/sasank-sfdcdev/public/tree/master/src/lwc/datatable.

---

Here is the generic component which you can use for exactly this functionality - https://github.com/sasank-sfdcdev/public/tree/master/src/lwc/upload  - Also this can be used in both AURA and LWC (pls note that this is in progress)

Using this component, you can:

1. Get the files owned by current user
2. Search for files
3. Use this in scenario where file has to be uploaded while creating any record like account/case etc.

Note that this uses another component which you can download from same location.

You can use it like below:

```
<template>
    <c-upload parent-id={parentId}
              label="Upload Files"
              accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,.png">
    </c-upload>
</template>
```

You will get the UI as below:

[image]

Comment: I have tried to use them, but could not find a way to handle the event - as you have said  `after clicking on done` - after clicking `Done` the variables that contain  `Uploaded File Names` do not refresh...

Comment: @ItaiShmida, did this not solve the issue?

Comment: - no, the whole reason I am trying to use a flow is not to develop. So if I need to develop the file uploader component, I will develop the whole flow in a lightning component. Thanks

Comment: added a generic component for file upload (in end of answer). Its still in progress. Let me know your requirements, will try to include them.

Answer (score 0):

from the upload element, you can store the uploaded file names in a text collection variable, just show those text collection in UI in next component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).