# a Component that Records a Video on ScreenFlow Salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow, upload, component, video

is possible to have a component that permits the recording of a video directly within a flow and then uploads it on salesforce or anywhere i want, like google drive?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question [File Upload component in Flow - no indication that files where uploaded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271431/file-upload-component-in-flow-no-indication-that-files-where-uploaded?rq=1) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File Upload component in Flow - no indication that files where uploaded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271431/file-upload-component-in-flow-no-indication-that-files-where-uploaded)

Comment: No, i already have this component.
I need a component that permits the recording of a video directly within a flow, as in the screenshot above.

Comment: Probably not possible to do through screen flow, you might want to try lwc and javascript. 
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-create-a-screen-recorder-in-javascript

Comment: ok, i will try it in lwc, thank's